# openssh-server's unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, debian, openssh

I just installed `debian-9.6.0-amd64-netinst.iso` and now trying to follow [SSH - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SSH#Installation_of_the_server) (Installation of the server) and running into following error:

[image: unmet dependecies]

Please advise.

I ran `apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade` before trying to install `openssh-server`.

Comment: Debian questions are off-topic here. Especially a question that is specific to Debian repositories. You can ask at our sister site [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: MOD: If my question is indeed off-topic here, please move it to wherever is appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: Some hints in general: if you ask the question somewhere else, make sure to paste the text instead posting a screenshot of text and include information which solutions from other **many** similar questions you tried and how they failed. This will help people to give you a decent answer.

Comment: @RoVo thank you for your hint. I couldn't paste text as I can't "ssh-in", therefor I paste a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing part:

> [SourcesList - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)